# Как пофиксить url или создание 404 ошибки?

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess

Есть у меня в главной директории файл `index.php`, а также папка `app`, в кот. находятся файлы по верстке. Так вот, я использовал `.htaccess` для того, чтобы путь к этим файлам был аля `localhost/about` вместо `localhost/app/about` и без расширения `.php`

Вот собственно и сам файл `.htacess`

```
RewriteRule ^about /_app/about.php [L,QSA]
```

Вроде в url все нормально работает. Но!! Когда я пишу после `about` любое число, слово (например, `localhost/about88888`), то все рано показывает страницу как-будто это просто `about`, хотя по идее должна быть ошибка ибо файла нет такого.

Такое же самое получается, когда я просматриваю запись типа `details?id=4` - все нормально, показывает информацию, а, если я допишу `?id=4gfdgf`, то все равно я останусь на этой странице, но данные будут пустые ибо нет такой записи в БД. (будет отображена просто верстка).

Пример вывода информации для записи `details`

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE id = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
  $details = $stmt->fetch();
```

Вопрос: как решить эту проблему? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Дописывайте указатель `$` на конец строки в условии. То есть вместо

   ```
   RewriteRule ^about /_app/about.php [L,QSA]
   ```

   пишите

   ```
   RewriteRule ^about$ /_app/about.php [L,QSA]
   ```
2. Тут вам нужно проверять, что пришло действительно число (только цифры в переменной). То есть после

   ```
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   ```

   нужно добавить проверку (функции is_int() и is_numeric() чуть не подходят)

   ```
   if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/u', $id))
   {
      header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
      exit;
   }
   ```

**UPD**

Такая переадресация

```
RewriteRule ^about(\/|\.php)?$ /_app/about.php [L,QSA]
```

должна сработать в трех случаях: `/about`, `/about/` и `/about.php`

Comment: спасибо. Заменил. Но дополнять адрес .php, слешом(/) в конце нельзя, а нужно мне.
И вот у меня в бд есть 5 записей, если я ввиду в ?id=55, то все равно покажется верстка, но без данных. Что в таком случае делать? нужно, чтобы написало "Не найдено"

Comment: @PoGiS, 1. где вы увидели, что я вам предлагаю слеш поставить в конец? 2. Получение и проверку параметров из url-а делайте до того как начали выводить содержимое страницы, тогда при ошибке в параметрах пустой верстки не будет, будет ошибка 404 в браузере.

Comment: 1. Нет, вы не поняли. Не вы предлагаете, а я спросил как это сделать, т.е. чтобы после about. можно поставить .php или слеш(about.php or about/) - все равно останемся на этой же странице. Без $ - работает, но тогда в адресную строку вводить можно что угодно, а с $ - не получается ничего

Comment: @PoGiS, обновил ответ.

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь!!